# findOne has no callback with MongoDB and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 2.0.6 with node.js and the mongodb-native module. I'm trying to create a database of different social media items and currently have tweets properly populating my database. I'd like to add a function that gets the most recent tweet ID (not mongo ID but a field called 'api_id') and returns it for use in an API call.

I followed [this great tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb) as the base for what I have but the findOne function seems to never hit its callback. I tried using findOne with the native Mongo ID serialization as well but no luck. I'm going to try a workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/617) for Mongo 1 but I don't think it will work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Find one by given criteria
updateSocial.prototype.findByCrit = function(crit, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, social_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        social_collection.findOne({api_type: crit}, function(error, result) {
            if( error )
                callback(error)
            else {
                callback(null, result);
            }
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Code looks fine so the problem may lay elsewhere.  Have you stepped through it?

Comment: How much data do you have? Is there an index on `api_type`? You could just be waiting for the DB.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) the findOne method doesn't have callback as second argument:

```
db.collection.findOne(query, projection)
```

where:

- **query**: Optional. Specifies query selection criteria using query operators.
- **projection**: Optional. Specifies the fields to return using projection operators. Omit this parameter to return all fields in the matching document.

So, you shouldn't expect Mongo to call your second argument after query is executed.